# How to apply lightbox to open a div?

Tags: html, lightbox

I have a div and i want to display it in a lightbox after click on a submit button

Comment: What lightbox plugin are you using?

Comment: Also, is this like a "success!" kind of div?

Comment: i have a div which have some pic and text also and i have a button when user click on that that div will b open but using java script not using css

Comment: It's essential to know what lightbox plugin you're using (unless you wrote your own)

Answer (score 6):

Let’s start with the CSS

```
 .black_overlay{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
z-index:1001;
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
opacity:.80;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);

 }


 .white_content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 25%;
left: 25%;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
padding: 16px;
border: 16px solid orange;
background-color: white;
z-index:1002;
overflow: auto;

 }
```

The black_overlay class is the layer that will make the web page seem to fade. It’s a black 80% opaque background as long and wide as the browser that will overlay the web page (look at the z-index) and at the moment is not shown (look at the display).

The white content class is the layer with the photo/login screen/whatever you want to appear in the Lightbox overlay. It’s a white layer to be placed over the black_overlay layer (look at the z-index, greater than the black_overlay one). The overflow allows you to have a scrollable content.

In the html file, put this line just before the tag

```
<div id="light" class="white_content">Hi, I am an happy lightbox</div><div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

Now, trig the action you want to open the Lightbox and insert this code:

```
document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').display='block';
```

For example, in a link would be:

```
 <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Hide me</a>
```

A complete example page could be

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
 <html>
<head>
    <title>LIGHTBOX EXAMPLE</title>
    <style>
    .black_overlay{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1001;
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        opacity:.80;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    }
    .white_content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 16px solid orange;
        background-color: white;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is the main content. To display a lightbox click <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">here</a></p>
    <div id="light" class="white_content">This is the lightbox content. <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Original source: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/